# VHDL generate statement increment by 2

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to use a generate statement to make a custom bit width version of my circuit. However, I need to increment N by 2 instead of 1. Is there a way to do this?

```
...
adders: for N in 1 to bits-1 generate
        mapping: RBNS port map(
            a => a(N downto N-1),
            b => b(N downto N-1),   
            sum => result(N downto N-1),
            cout => carry(N),
            cin => carry(N-1)
        );
        end generate;
carry(0) <= '1'
...
```

Comment: You can also use an `if ... generate` inside the `for ... generate` statement, to only generate a circuit if the loop counter is even.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can multiply the iterator :

```
adders: for N in 1 to bits/2-1 generate
        mapping: RBNS port map(
            a => a(N*2 downto N*2-1),
            b => b(N*2 downto N*2-1),   
            sum => result(N*2 downto N*2-1),
            cout => carry(N*2),
            cin => carry(N*2-1)
        );
        end generate;
carry(0) <= '1'
```

... etc